# user groups in joomla 

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have to type of registration in my website (employers and job seekers) 
I want to hide some modules on (joob seekers) type

but in the access type of my template joomla i have 3 type (public register special) and administration panel  user groupe i cant find the 2 types of registration (employers & job seekers)

i fond just this Access Control Levels in this web site
http://help.joomla.org/content/view/228/153/1/2/

How can i use this 2 type of registration in an access type ??

or

How to create a new 2 user groups (employers & job seekers) in joomla 1.5 ??

Comment: You need to start your search in http://docs.joomla.org/ not the old help.joomla.org site.  Adding and configuring user groups and levels is better done with Joomla 1.7 so my best advice would be to migrate the site and go from there.

Comment: I agree with Dean completely.  Joomla 1.7 was designed specifically with things like this in mind, and as Joomla 1.5 approaches the end of it's support cycle, 1.8 will be coming out as the next Long Term Support version - so it's best to upgrade/migrate early and be prepared so things aren't breaking later.

Comment: I try to use J2XML for the migration but i dont know how to export my old web site on joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I have to maintain about a half dozen Joomla1.5 sites, and have had great success with [noixACL](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/7010)